# How can I create an array of states in React using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a number, *n*, that can be any value and I want to render *n* input fields while keeping track of each input's state but I'm having trouble figuring out how. For example, if *n = 3*, I want to render something like this:

```html
<div>
    <input onChange={(e) => setValue1(e.target.value)}/>
    <input onChange={(e) => setValue2(e.target.value)}/>
    <input onChange={(e) => setValue3(e.target.value)}/>
< /div>
```

In this example, I would manually need to create three states: value1, value2, value3. My goal is to have it dynamic so if in the future I change *n* to 4 or any other number, I don't have to manually create more states and mess with the component. Is there a good way to accomplish this using hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a inputs state in order to track every input:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(Array(10).fill(''));
  const inputChangedHandler = (e, index) => {
    const inputsUpdated = inputs.map((input, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        return e.target.value;
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    });
    setInputs(inputsUpdated);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map((input, i) => (
        <input onChange={e => inputChangedHandler(e, i)} value={input} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check here, how things work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sdzoqh

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array with `useState` hook of size `num` that is passed from its parent and then using its index i.e. `i` you can change its input value using `setValue` function.

[CODESANDBOX DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-rain-9zf0c?file=/src/App.js:58-606)

*Just for DEMO purpose and make the `input` come to a new line so I've wrapped it into `div`.*

```
export default function App({ num }) {
  const [arr, setValue] = useState(Array(num).fill(""));
  console.log(arr);

  function onInputChange(index, event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setValue((os) => {
      const temp = [...os];
      temp[index] = event.target.value;
      return temp;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((n, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <input onChange={(e) => onInputChange(i, e)} value={n} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would create a custom hook to generate my inputs like

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CreateInput = (n) => {
    const array = new Array(n).fill("");
    const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        setValueInput({
            ...valueInput,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const Input = array.map((_, i) => (
        <input key={i} name={i} onChange={handleChange} />
    ));

    return {
        Input,
    };
};

const Inputs = () => {
    const { Input } = CreateInput(3);

    console.log(Input);

    return <div>{Input}</div>;
};

export default Inputs;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with an array in the state, with the values in the inputs. Initialize with empty strings

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(Array(n).fill(""))
const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const copy = values;
    copy[i] = e.target.value
    setValues(copy)
}
return (
    <div>
        {Array(n).map((x,i) => (
            <input value={values[i]} onChange={e => handleChange(e,i)} />
))}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use useState([]) with array as default value for example

import "./styles.css";
import React, {  useState } from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  const n = 3;
  const [values, setValues] = useState(new Array(n).fill(1, 0, n));

  const handleChange = (i, value) => {
    const v = [...values];
    v[i] = value;
    setValues(v);
    
  };

  const inputsRendrer = (values) => {
    return values.map((v, i) => {
      return (
        <input
          key={i}
          value={values[i]}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(i, event.target.value)}
        />
      );
    });
  };
  return <div className="App">{inputsRendrer(values)}</div>;
```

}

```
new Array(n).fill(1, 0, n) // this create new array with values of 1 and length of n`
```